# Enable all .NET traces at a specific severity level

Tags: .net, trace

I am learning how to use the .NET Tracing framework, and I am stuck trying to enable some fairly simple logging.

I'd like to log all messages that are at "Warning" or above to a text file, using the `MyApplication.exe.config` file.  I would like to enable this for all sources in the application, without having to specify them all in the config file.

In my application code I am calling `System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();` and in my `.config` I have tried the following:

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
        <listeners>
            <add
                name="myListener"
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="Trace.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

But this does not seem to log anything.

My only success has come from explicitly listing all the sources in the `.config` file; which I want to avoid as I want to catch all sources (even those I don't control).

Answer (score 0):

The .NET tracing framework does not support this. It was designed from the perspective that you should only be logging to diagnose a particular problem, so you would (presumably) know which trace sources would be applicable.

If you need to capture all logging, I'd use [moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) to hook `TraceSource` construction or poll `TraceSource.tracesources` (using Reflection). Moles is preferable because it's cleaner, supported, and you won't lose any messages. Note that both of these approaches are not acceptable for production code; they can be used during development only.